# Cannot Update WCF Service Reference after adding a method that returns an array or list

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am trying to test a WCF web service and am having problems when I introduce complicated return types.  I have tried to keep this simple to start and am verifying I can pass data between the web service and a client.  I have created the following files: MyService.svc, MyService.cs, and IMyService.cs.  This is done in ASP.NET C#.

MyService.cs looks like this:

```
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
        }

        public bool BoolTest()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public string StrTest(string input)
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
```

IMyService.cs Looks like this:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService{
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork();

        [OperationContract]
        bool BoolTest();

        [OperationContract]
        string StrTest(string input);

    }
```

I have a console application which I connect to the Service above with a "Service Reference".  When I use the code shown above, everything links up okay and I am able to make calls to the functions provided by the web service.

My problem occurs when I try to return anything more complicated such as an array, a list, or a custom object.  After I add a function to the Web Service with one of these return types, then attempt to update the Service Reference in the Console Application, the reference fails to update and is lost.

Here is MyService.cs with the additional method that causes the failure:

```
        public class MyService : IMyService
        {
            public void DoWork()
            {
            }

            public bool BoolTest()
            {
                return false;
            }

            public string StrTest(string input)
            {
                return input;
            }

            public string [] StrArrTest()
            {
                string[] s = new[] { "test", "test2" };
                return s;
            }
        }
```

Here is a copy of IMyService.cs with the additional method added that causes the error:

```
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IMyService{
            [OperationContract]
            void DoWork();

            [OperationContract]
            bool BoolTest();

            [OperationContract]
            string StrTest(string input);

            [OperationContract]
            string [] StrArrTest();

        }
```

If I use a `List<string>` as a return type or `MyObject` as a return type it also fails.
I am guessing there is some sort of serialization needed but am having a hard time tracking down exactly what I need to do.

Additional bits of information that might be helpful...  The client and host are running on the same machine. When I access http://localhost/MyService.svc in a web browser there aren't any errors shown.  When I access http://localhost/MyService.svc?wsdl a descent sized xml document appears.

Can anyone help explain what I need to do so I can return arrays and lists of objects in the web service?

I found this similar question, [why does my silverlight reference to my wcf service blow up when I add a method to the wcf service that returns a generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505045/why-does-my-silverlight-reference-to-my-wcf-service-blow-up-when-i-add-a-method), but it applies to SilverLight which I am not using.  I took a look at the Reference.cs file mentioned in the post, when everything is working it is populated with a bunch of stuff.  When the reference is not updated correctly (after the method that returns an array is added), the Reference.cs file is empty with the exception of a comment about the file being auto-generated.

Comment: did you try to remove and add again

Comment: I had typically just been updating the service reference but to be sure, I went ahead and removed it completely and added again.  When I added again, it would not add when the method that returns an array was included.  I comment the method out, update the service reference, and it adds.  One side note, when I add the service reference and it fails, an entry appears in the "Service Reference" folder of VS even though there doesn't appear to be anything I can directly use.  So same results with a remove and add as with an update.